# Running Jason applications in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, agent, multi-agent

When I want to run my .mas2j file in Eclipse, I always have to right click the file and then select "Run as Jason application". Is there a way to add a shortcut to do this?

Comment: Are there any _Jason_ commands in _Window > Preferences: General > Keys_ which can be bound to a shortcut? If selecting the file to run and hitting Alt+Shift+X, what commands shows the dialog that pops up?

Comment: No Jason commands there, Alt+Shift+X show commands to run as Java, Ant, JUnit and Maven.

Comment: Too bad. You could report this as a feature request to the development team of the Jason Eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Jason's "Run" button should be added to eclipse toolbar ("Step 14" of [jason eclipse-plugin installation guide](http://jason.sourceforge.net/mini-tutorial/eclipse-plugin/)) and it is supposed to work. Anyway, you can save some time using shell, following instructions in [jason's github page](https://github.com/jason-lang/jason):

```
git clone https://github.com/jason-lang/jason.git
cd jason
gradle config
```

And run a project using a command like bellow:

```
jason examples/gold-miners-II/miners.mas2j
```

Another way, and actually my recommendation is moving to [JaCaMo](http://jacamo.sourceforge.net) (which has Jason embedded). JaCaMo offers a [gradle](https://gradle.org/install/) script for your projects. You can easily download JaCaMo from the repository and create a project from zero in one shot (first, go to your project root folder and then type):

```
curl -s -O http://jacamo.sourceforge.net/nps/np07.gradle
gradle -b np07.gradle --console=plain
```

After downloading JaCaMo, the script will ask you to type a name for your project, for instance, "test". So, go to "test" folder and type:

```
gradle run
```

The just created JaCaMo project should launch after this command. Besides good compiling performance, another advantage is that gradle will manage package dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually the issue with uncategorized commands in Eclipse. I had the same issue with the `Run JaCaMo Application` option. In order to see all your plugin commands:

Go to `Preferences` -> `General` -> `Keys`. Click on `Filters`... and de-select `Filter uncategorized commands` then `Ok`.

Then you should be able to find the desired command in the `Command` list and add a preferred `Binding`.

*Note:* If Eclipse offers a command, it should be listed in the [pop-up window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ibId.png) that appears when hitting the [`Show a table of all available commands` button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pLIR.png) of the Oomph toolbar. The table shows all the available commands, where you can find them, and all the defined shortcut keys.